# Trailing return type and rvalues

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, effective-c++

I'm reading Scott Meyers's *Effective Modern C++* and I'm trying on my machine the example he provides for the *Deducing Types* chapter.

He provides this function:

```
template <typename Container, typename Index>
auto decltype_test_1(Container& c, Index i) -> decltype(c[i])
{
  return c[i];
}
```

And then it uses the function in this way:

```
std::deque<int> d;
…
decltype_test_1(d, 5) = 10; // authenticate user, return d[5],
                          // then assign 10 to it;
                          // this won't compile!
```

Saying that it won't compile. I tried with MSVC and it does compile. I wrote the following in the `main`:

```
std::deque<int> d;
d.push_back(0);
d.push_back(1);
d.push_back(2);

decltype_test_1(d, 0) = 10;

for each (auto item in d)
  cout << item << endl;
```

I don't understand why it compiles and, most of all, it shows `10` as the first element of the deque. For what he explains this code is wrong. Why does it work here? What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like there's an example with `decltype` where he says it works fine, followed by an example without `decltype` where he says it's not quite correct. The function call is part of the latter. And of course, there's a third one with `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: your second snippet is calling a function `authAndAccess` while the first one defines `decltype_test_1`. I do not have the book, thus I dont know if it is a typo...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That comment is not about the C++11 example with the trailing decltype, it's about the C++14 version with `auto` type deduction:

```
template <typename Container, typename Index>
auto decltype_test_1(Container& c, Index i) //no trailing return
{
  return c[i];
}
```

Using this version, the example will fail to compile, because the type will be deduced as a value rather than a reference, so you can't directly assign to the result of a call to the function.

As is indicated on the next page of the book, the way to get the correct type deduced without a trailing return type is to use `decltype(auto)` instead of `auto`.

```
template <typename Container, typename Index>
decltype(auto) decltype_test_1(Container& c, Index i)
{
  return c[i];
}
```

Comment: so in the C++11 case, that `decltype(c[i])` will return the reference to `c[i]`, am I right?

Comment: @Agostino indeed, have a look at the compiler errors for [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e55a5cbdf7f46b7) to see the difference.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one thing, not related with the question, but I'd like to know what `template <typename>struct tt;` means, where can I read about it? Can you provide a link? Thanks again

Comment: @Agostino it's just a hacky way to get the compiler to show you the type it has deduced by declaring a class template and never defining it. Meyers actually shows an analogous approach in Item 4 of the book you're reading.